# Cross folder searching of Exchange using Exchange Web Services

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, ews-managed-api

Is there a way to search Exchange using the EWS Managed API for all email messages across ALL folders.  I'm using the FindItems API call -- but that appears to require that the search be confined to a single folder.

```
   private void InternalPurgeProcessFolder(FolderId folderId, ExchangeService service, SearchFilter searchCriteria) {

        Logger.Info("Processing folder {0}", folderId.FolderName);

        int pageSize = _runtimeParameters.ExchangeRetrievalPageSize;
        ItemView itemView = new ItemView(pageSize);
        itemView.PropertySet = Utils.BasicPropertySet();
        const int maxInterationsForTesting = 2;
        int iterations = 0;
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
        do {
            ++iterations;
            Logger.Debug("Start of iteration {0}", iterations);
            findResults = service.FindItems(folderId, searchCriteria, itemView);
            _dumper.ListDatesAndSubjectsBrief(findResults);
            itemView.Offset += pageSize;
        } while ((findResults.MoreAvailable) && (iterations < maxInterationsForTesting));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find items across folders you can create a [search folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.searchfolder.aspx) and in the [SearchFolderParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.searchfolderparameters.aspx) set the RootFolderIds to the root folder of the mailbox and the traversal mode to SearchFolderTraversal.Deep.